# Can't access virtual terminals after manually starting an X server

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, x-server, display-manager

I'm working on a display manager. When an X server is already started, my display manager works fine and is able to log in a user. However, in order for it to be a proper display manager, it needs to be able to start an X server itself.

From looking at the output of `ps aux | grep X`, and by examining the source code of another lightweight display manager (SLiM), I think my display manager should execute the following command:

```
/usr/bin/Xorg.bin :0 vt1
```

This is assuming that there is currently no other display manager/X server running.

The problem is that when my program runs that command or when I run that command manually, I get switched to the virtual terminal that I specify, and then the system "hangs". I'm not actually sure if it's hanging, or just that I can't access other virtual terminals (I think it's the latter). Here is the Xorg.log after I rebooted the machine:

```
[   631.692] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.3
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[   631.692] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   631.692] Build Operating System: Linux 3.18.1-1-ARCH x86_64 
[   631.692] Current Operating System: Linux arch 3.17.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 7 23:43:32 UTC 2014 x86_64
[   631.692] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=5ba710b1-c7b7-410d-baed-d6670f818d56 rw quiet
[   631.692] Build Date: 29 December 2014  01:09:58PM
[   631.693]  
[   631.693] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[   631.693]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   631.693] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   631.693] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan  3 23:38:54 2015
[   631.865] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   631.865] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   631.911] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   631.911] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   631.911] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   631.911] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   631.918] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   631.918] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[   631.918] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   631.918] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   631.918] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   631.918] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   631.996] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/".
[   631.996]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   631.996]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/OTF/").
[   632.040] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/".
[   632.040]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   632.040]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi/").
[   632.040] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/".
[   632.040]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   632.040]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi/").
[   632.040] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/Type1/
[   632.040] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   632.040] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   632.047] (II) Loader magic: 0x818d80
[   632.047] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   632.047]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   632.047]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[   632.047]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[   632.047]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[   632.051] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c1
[   632.052] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[   632.053] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 10 paused 0
[   632.053] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   632.054] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[   632.058] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0116:103c:185d rev 9, Mem @ 0xc0000000/4194304, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64
[   632.058] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 1002:6760:103c:185d rev 0, Mem @ 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xc6500000/131072, I/O @ 0x00005000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   632.058] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[   632.059] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   632.097] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   632.114] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   632.114]    compiled for 1.16.3, module version = 1.0.0
[   632.114]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[   632.114] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   632.114] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   632.114] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   632.161] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   632.161]    compiled for 1.16.3, module version = 2.99.917
[   632.161]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   632.161]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[   632.161] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   632.162] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[   632.162] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[   632.162] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[   632.162] (++) using VT number 2

[   632.177] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20140725
[   632.184] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
[   632.184] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx
[   632.184] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   632.184] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   632.184] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[   632.184] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   632.184] (**) intel(0): Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
[   632.184] (**) intel(0): Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
[   632.184] (II) intel(0): Output LVDS1 has no monitor section
[   632.184] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output LVDS1
[   632.184] (II) intel(0): Enabled output LVDS1
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[   632.185] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[   632.185] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[   632.185] (--) intel(0): Output LVDS1 using initial mode 1366x768 on pipe 0
[   632.185] (--) intel(0): Output HDMI1 using initial mode 1920x1080 on pipe 1
[   632.185] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[   632.185] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   632.185] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   632.185] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   632.185] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   632.185] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[   632.185] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[   632.185] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[   632.185] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[   632.201] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Sandybridge (gen6, gt2) backend
[   632.201] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[   632.201] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   632.202] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[   632.202] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[   632.204] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[   632.204] (==) intel(0): display hotplug detection enabled
[   632.204] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   632.204] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[   632.204] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: i965
[   632.204] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[   632.204] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[   632.204] (--) RandR disabled
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[   632.390] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[   632.391] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[   632.391] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[   632.405] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   632.407] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied [13]
[   632.408] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 1, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   632.413] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Permission denied [13]
[   632.413] (WW) intel(0): failed to restore desired modes on VT switch
[   632.413] (EE) intel(0): sna_mode_check: invalid state found on pipe 0, disabling CRTC:7
[   632.413] (EE) intel(0): sna_mode_check: invalid state found on pipe 1, disabling CRTC:11
[   632.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[   632.769] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   632.769] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[   632.813] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[   632.876] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   632.876]    compiled for 1.16.2, module version = 2.9.1
[   632.876]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   632.876]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[   632.878] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 18 paused 1
[   632.878] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[   632.904] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event16)
[   632.904] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   632.905] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event16 13:80 fd 18 paused 1
[   632.905] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
[   632.930] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[   632.931] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   632.931] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   632.931] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event11)
[   632.931] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   632.933] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event11 13:75 fd 18 paused 1
[   632.933] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:75
[   632.955] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[   632.955] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   632.956] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 18 paused 1
[   632.956] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[   632.984] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Digital PCBeep (/dev/input/event6)
[   632.984] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   632.984] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   632.985] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[   632.985] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   632.985] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   632.985] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
[   632.985] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   632.985] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   632.986] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[   632.986] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   632.986] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   632.986] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event13)
[   632.986] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   632.988] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event13 13:77 fd 18 paused 1
[   632.988] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:77
[   633.048] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   633.048] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   633.048] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   633.049] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Receiver (/dev/input/event14)
[   633.049] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   633.050] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event14 13:78 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.050] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:78
[   633.104] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1 (/dev/input/event12)
[   633.104] (**) Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   633.105] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event12 13:76 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.105] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:76
[   633.160] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1 (/dev/input/event15)
[   633.161] (**) Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[   633.161] (**) Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   633.162] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event15 13:79 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.162] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:79
[   633.224] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsft Microsoft Wireless Desktop Receiver 3.1 (/dev/input/mouse2)
[   633.224] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   633.224] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   633.224] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[   633.224] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   633.226] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.226] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
[   633.290] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event10)
[   633.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[   633.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   633.290] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   633.290] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   633.291] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[   633.346] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   633.346]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 1.8.1
[   633.346]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   633.346]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[   633.348] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event10 13:74 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.348] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:74
[   633.397] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   633.397] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[   633.397] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer (/dev/input/event2)
[   633.397] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   633.397] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   633.398] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer (/dev/input/js0)
[   633.398] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   633.398] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   633.399] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event5)
[   633.399] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   633.400] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 18 paused 1
[   633.400] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
```

I'm using Arch Linux with X server version 1.16.3. One person on #xorg on IRC confirmed that on their system, running the command I specified still allows them to access other virtual terminals, although they're using xorg version 1.15 and not on Arch Linux.

Can anyone else confirm that their system does/doesn't behave as I described (you'll need to restart your system if it behaves like mine). How can I start the X server manually and still have access to the other virtual terminals?

Comment: `Release Date: 2014-12-20` -> That's not really stock Arch is it?  Anyway, v. 1.14.4 (Fedora 20) did not cause the problem you describe, although it did annoyingly steal tty1 from a (different) logged in user.  I don't think you should specify anything there.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the info. I'm starting to wonder if it's a problem with the 1.16 release of X server. It would be really useful if someone with the same version as me could try it out.

Comment: What did you try to access other virtual terminals? Ctrl+Alt+F1? Can you log in over SSH? Does the machine respond to pings? Can you kill the X server with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace (this may need to be enabled in xorg.conf)?

Comment: @Gilles, yes, I used Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] with no success. Trying to SSH in is a great idea, let me try it out. Ctrl+Alt+Backspace didn't work when I tried it, but I didn't know I had to enable it. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Gilles I am able to SSH into the machine. I see that there are two `/usr/bin/Xorg.bin processes` running, one with sudo and one without (which is weird, I only ran one with sudo). I can kill the X process, but the computer still stays stuck on that screen and I still can't access other virtual terminals.

Comment: Does `sudo chvt 1` from the SSH connection help? In any case, this is usually a symptom of a video driver bug. Try a different version of the video driver (possibly an older one), or a different video driver (proprietary instead of free or vice versa). Try searching the web for your exact graphics card model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://www.archlinux.org/news/xorg-server-116-is-now-available/

> X is now rootless with the help of systemd-logind, this also means
>   that it must be launched from the same virtual terminal as was used to
>   log in, redirecting stderr also breaks rootless login. The old root
>   execution behavior can be restored through the Xorg.wrap config file
>   (man xorg.wrap). Please note that launching X through a login-manager
>   (gdm, kdm, ...) doesn't yet provide rootless access.

I was trying to launch X on a different tty than the one I was on.